# How to highlight multiple matches?

Tags: bash, git, perl, zsh

I have a shell function (which I use in Zsh, but it should work in Bash) that highlights matching text in output, so I can quickly find things.

```
function highlight() {
  perl -pe "s/$1/\e[1;31;43m$&\e[0m/g"
}
```

This is very handy, but it only works with a single argument.  If I had a fixed number of arguments, I could do something like:

```
perl -pe "s/abc/def/; s/fgh/hij/;"
```

but of course that's crazy.  How can I make this work with an unspecified number of arguments?

My particular use case (in case it makes a difference) is to pipe a list of Git branches through it, and highlight the output of `$(git branch --no-merged master)` in the list, so I can see all unmerged branches highlighted in the context of a larger list of all branches.

Comment: Is it okay for this function to only work with stdin, or do you plan on supporting filename arguments as well?  How do you plan on distinguishing the two if you handle filename arguments?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily accomplish this by leveraging a special parameter in bash and by simplifying your perl regular expression. I can explain them both a bit further:

**Bash/Zsh Special Parameter**

See the man page for more info. (https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)

In bash you can access all of the arguments passed to a function using the `$*` special parameter, this allows you to easily handle a variable number of parameters. In your case, you want to search for and highlight each of the passed values. The nice thing about the `$*` is that it will separate the parameters by whatever value is set for the `IFS` variable.

**Multi-Matching Regular Expression**

Rather than duplicate the matching logic by adding extra rules, you can simply use an `OR` conditional in your expression to search for multiple words in your document. This is done by adding a pipe (`|`) between the words you are searching for.

Putting it all together, we can use a function like this to support searching for multiple words in a document.

```
function highlight() {
  IFS='|'
  perl -pe "s/$*/\e[1;31;43m$&\e[0m/g"
}
```

This is a fairly simple example and it will even work correctly if your target string contains spaces like this:

`highlight "my string"`

Comment: This is brilliant, but it's not working for me.  My function which lists branches is `b--`, and even after I filter out the `*` from the current branch I get errors: `b-- | highlight "$(git branch --no-merged master | sed 's/*//')"` gives me:

Comment: `Number found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "--352"
 (Missing operator before 352?)
Number found where operator expected at -e line 2, near "--459"
 (Missing operator before 459?)
Unknown regexp modifier "/h" at -e line 2, at end of line
  (Might be a runaway multi-line // string starting on line 1)`

Comment: `syntax error at -e line 1, near "--352"
syntax error at -e line 2, near "--459"
syntax error at -e line 3, near ";}continue{print or die qq(-p destination: $"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line $$ string starting on line 2)
Missing right curly or square bracket at -e line 3, at end of line
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: Some examples of the output of `b--` (where dates appear on the same line before branch names)  are `2019-10-11  feature/smartsheet-integration--447
2019-10-12  config/update-region-mapping--485
2019-10-17  feature/check-level-5-in-xlsx--490
2019-10-17  master
2019-10-18  feature/hide-tooltip-with-modal--459`

Comment: You're running into the problem that the `/` in the data is messing with the `/` perl delimiters I think. Try `perl -pe "s#$*#\e[1;31;43m$&\e[0m#g"`.

Comment: @JeffY is correct, I also think that perhaps other special characters need to be escaped. There might be a simpler way to do this, would need to investigate some other tools or options for the regular expression.